# Layout for spinner on android API >= 7

Tags: android, spinner

I want to make spinner on Android API 7 and higher which looks like this (I don't any pop-up/dialog things)

[image]

example from: [developer android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

How to do it?

Comment: See the [`android:spinnerMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#attr_android:spinnerMode) attribute (only available since API level 11).

Comment: is any idea to to use this solution on lower API? I don't know my is any library or sth to this problem?

Comment: [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) may support this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere). It's a library which is designed to "bring Holo Theme from Android 4.1 to 2.1 and above". You can try out the [Demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.holoeverywhere.demo) if it fits your needs. Or - if you don't have a 2.1 device - use the [apk](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.holoeverywhere/demo) (download - binary) to load it onto an emulator.